# Exception while Installing Scrapy On Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: python, macos, installation, scrapy

I am trying to install Scrapy on my Macbook Pro running Yosemite. I tried following the documentation on their site for instillation by running the following command in terminal.

`pip install Scrapy`

During instillation the following exception is thrown:

```
Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6 py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1435, in install
requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 671, in install
self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 901, in move_wheel_files
pycompile=self.pycompile,
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 215, in move_wheel_files
clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 205, in clobber
os.makedirs(destdir)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
    OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy'
```

Any thoughts on how to proceed?

Comment: For some reason using
        easy_install Scrapy
installed everything perfectly..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use:

```
sudo easy_install Scrapy
```

it has worked for me (MacOS El Capitan).

Answer (score 3):

**Trouble installing lxml preq for  Scrapy 
, I Figured it out, This is how**

I had trouble installing the prerequisites for Scrapy.  Particularly lxml library preventing the Scrapy from installing.  I eventually figured it out.
Im running mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.1

## To install Scrapy you have to have the following things installed:

1. Python -  I installed 2.7.6
2. pip - I installed 6.0.8
3. lxml - I installed 3.4.2
4. OpenSSL - This comes preinstalled in all operating systems #

Here were the commands

## //INSTALLING lxml

*UserNames-MacBook:~ username$ sudo env ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future STATIC_DEPS=true pip install lxml*

//Result - Successfully installed lxml-3.4.2

## //INSTALLING SCRAPY

*UserNames-MacBook:~ username$ sudo easy_install Scrapy*

//Result - Installed /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/w3lib-1.11.0-py2.7.egg
Finished processing dependencies for Scrapy

//Check to see if Scrapy installed correctly
*UserNames-MacBook:~ username$ scrapy --version*

//Result - Scrapy 0.24.5 - no active project

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo pip install Scrapy
```

If this also won't work then try this:

```
sudo apt-get install python-scrapy
```

Comment: I used easy_install Scrapy and i worked, thanks for your suggestions though.

Answer (score 0):

Try ignoring the already installed dependencies:

`pip install Scrapy --ignore-installed`